# When is config file read?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a Windows Service that uses custom LibraryA.  LibraryA has a service reference to ServiceB, which also created endpoint entries in LibraryA's app.config file.  The Windows Service does not have entries in its app.config for ServiceB.

I get the error below when LibraryB tries to reference ServiceB:

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'service name' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.  This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

The Windows Service is the host.  I'm guessing if I copy the service config info from LibraryA's config file into the Windows Service config file, everything will work fine.  But why isn't LibraryA's config file being read at all, especially since it has the config info?

Comment: Can you get to the endpoint in a web-browser? That will indicate in the config is wrong or whether the service isn't working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint configuration is read from the configuration file that belongs to the entry assembly. That is in this case not `LibraryA`, but the application that uses `LibraryA` to connect to the remote service.

You need to add the client endpoint configuration (used by `LibraryA`) in the corresponding configuration file.

The config file from `LibraryA` will not be read by this application. You could try sharing configuration sections using `externalsource`, but that isn't always practical. It is usually better to let every app have it's own complete and standalone configuration.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that the resulting config file is valid. i.e. no double `<system.servicemodel>` section for example.